# Compute Engine option is disabled in VS 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I was trying to create a simple .NET Core 2 Web API using "ASP.NET on Google Cloud Platform" template in Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 7 x64.
I am following this Quickstart guide - https://cloud.google.com/tools/visual-studio/docs/quickstart

On step 12 when I was trying to Publish using "Publish to Google Cloud..." the option "Compute Engine" was disabled.

[image]

I can see the VM listed in "Google Cloud Explorer" window under "Google Compute Engine".

Also in appsettings.json I can see the Google.ProjectId correctly set to Project name.
I have already deleted and recreated the VM once to no avail.

How do I get "Compute Engine" option enabled?

Comment: I'll ping the person who can answer this for sure, but I *suspect* it's because it's an ASP.NET Core project rather than ASP.NET "classic".

Comment: I reported this issue months ago: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-visualstudio/issues/846

Comment: @JonSkeet I tried what Amanda suggested and it worked. For now I'll complete the current skill with it. However, I'll keep this question open and wait for your response. This is a bug for sure :)

Comment: @GauravMathur: I wouldn't say it's a bug in the extension - I believe the feature is working as intended, but there could be a feature request here as well.

Comment: @JonSkeet looks like for now it doesn't support .NET Core

Comment: More ASP.NET Core than .NET Core specifically. We may address that feature request at some point - it's a matter of prioritization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @jonskeet said, you probably can't deploy your project to Compute Engine because the project you are trying to deploy is targeting .Net Core.
I realize that the steps you were following are telling you to create a .Net Core project and then deploy it to the VM, that's not right, and we'll change it.

Create a new project selecting .Net Framework instead of .Net Core and you should be able to deploy it to the VM.

The following image would be the right one to follow on Step 7 of *Create an Asp.Net project*

[image: Step 7 on Create an Asp.Net project]

**UPDATE:**

As of March 2018 not being able to publish .NET Core applications in Compute Engine through Google Cloud Visual Studio Extension is not a bug, it is working as intended. Using the extension, you can publish .NET Framework applications to Compute Engine and .NET Core applications to App Engine Flex and to Container Engine. You can see [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-visualstudio/issues/846).

What is a bug is the image used on Step 7 of *Create an Asp.Net project* on the [Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/tools/visual-studio/docs/quickstart) you were following, since it is showing the creation of a .NET Core targetting application for publication in GCE. That is already being fixed.

If you want to deploy a .NET Core application to App Engine using the Google Cloud Visual Studio Extension you can follow this other [Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/quickstart).

Comment: Thanks @Amanda Tarafa Mas, it worked. However, I am keeping this question open and waiting for Jon Skeet to reply

Comment: @GauravMathur, updated my answer, with what is a bug (Quickstart) and what is intended behaviour (not supporting .NET Core apps deployment to GCE through the Google Cloud Visual Studio Extension)

Comment: I have accepted the answer. I was about to write that you should disable the "Compute Engine" option in case a user select .NET Core then realize that's what the tool does, it somehow not intuitive :)