# How do I enable App engine flex

Tags: visual-studio, google-app-engine, asp.net-mvc-5, google-cloud-platform

[image]

---

app.yaml file

---

```
  runtime: aspnetcore
  env: flex

 # This sample incurs costs to run on the App Engine flexible environment. 
 # The settings below are to reduce costs during testing and are not 
 appropriate
 # for production use. For more information, see:
 # https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuring-your-
 app-with-app-yaml
 manual_scaling:
 instances: 1
 resources:
 cpu: 1
 memory_gb: 0.5
 disk_size_gb: 10
```

I'm trying to deploy my .NET MVC5 app to google cloud platforms via visual studios 2017 (on Windows 7) but for some reasons, App Engine Flex is disabled.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show your `app.yaml` file? Also check this guide (if you didn't already): https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/quickstart

Comment: I have followed the guide and manually created an app.yaml file but still it is not working and I dont know why. Check the post for app.yaml file. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only .NET Core targetting apps are supported in App Engine Flex. I suspect your app is targeting .NET Framework.

If you are using Google Cloud project template to create your project select .NET Core as the target framework as shown in the image below.

[image: .NET Core Target Framework]

And, as stated in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49310154/1122643), Google Cloud Visual Studio Extension only supports Compute Engine publication of .NET Framework targettin apps.

That is:

- .NET Core apps on App Engine Flex and Container Engine.
- .NET Framework apps on Compute Engine VMs.

Comment: Thanks; that's what is realize after watching some YouTube videos. In a way, that sucks because I already created my app using .NET Framework and I dont think I can change it from .NET framework to .NET core and I dont wanna import files and stuff. But I ll find a way. Thanks.